# How to identify a mixture of poisson distribution and Gaussian distribution from the data?

Tags: r, mixture-distribution, finite-mixture-model

Here is the distribution of the data.
[image]

It seeme to me that it is a mixture of a poisson distribution at the begining of zero value and a Gaussian distribution. I also used the `fitdistr()` function in R to estimate the significance of the front part. And the p-value of seems to be more significant for poisson distribution than Gaussian distribution.

```
ties should not be present for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
    One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  ex.temp$RNA
D = 0.23033, p-value = 0.02869
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

> # KS-test for poisson distribution
> ks.test(ex.temp$RNA,"ppois",lambda = mean(ex.temp$RNA))
ties should not be present for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
    One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  ex.temp$RNA
D = 0.75719, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

**So my question is how to identify these kind of mixture of distribution so that we can separate the data into two groups, and what's the method of it?**

I am aware that `mclust()` function in R can separate Gaussian mixture models, but as I said, the front part is more like a poisson than a Gaussian.

Thanks for any responds and helps!!!

Comment: Poisson random variables are natural numbers $(0, 1, 2, \ldots)$ whereas a Gaussian can take any real number. A mixture of the two makes no sense.  Are your data continuous valued or just natural numbers?

Comment: @jcken, they are continuous values. Thanks

Comment: as long as no values are exactly zero, you could try fitting a gaussian mixture to $\log (\text{value})$